# Insertion Issue in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

User table:

```
var user = connection.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: sequelize.STRING
  },
  age: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER
  }
}, {
  classMethods: {
    insertData: function(sql, data) {
      this.create({
        name: data.name,
        age: data.age
      }).then(function() {
        console.log("successful insertion");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

address table:

```
var address = connection.define('address', {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  content: sequelize.TEXT
}, {
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(model) {
      var user = model.user;
      user.hasMany(address);
    },
    insertData: function(data) {
      this.create({
        content: data.content,
        userId: data.id
      }).then(function() {
        console.log("working ");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Now how do i insert data in field `userId` of table **address** which gets created after the relationship between *user* and *address*.

Inserting directly with field name as stated below doesnt work.

```
insertData: function(data) {
  this.create({
    content: data.content,
    userId: data.id
  }).then(function() {
    console.log("working ");
  });
}
```

Comment: You should do `return this.create...` inside `insertData` method. What is the SQL query generated when you run `insertData(data)` on `address` model?

Comment: INSERT INTO "addresses" ("id","content","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,'addr2','2017-02-17 14:25:22.246 +00:00','2017-02-17 14:25:22.246 +00:00') RETURNING *;

Comment: Does your `addresses` table contains `userId` column? Do you use `sequelize.sync()` to synchronise the database or you use migrations?

Comment: The `user` table contains the column `userId` and the relationship exists between the table `user` and `address`  i.e `user.hasMany(address)`
After executing query `select * from addresses` i get the column `userId` in `address` table  as a foreign key .

Comment: I reconstructed this situation and everything seems to work fine. Are you sure your `data` object passed to the `address.insertData` method is surely `{ content: 'some content', id: 'user id here' }`?

Comment: Yeah i checked it . It contains the correct data .

Comment: The issue was in the object from which i was calling .Apparently "this"  keyword had no relationship . It only contains the model and no relationship. So i passed the whole object through some other file and it works now . Don't know the reason though .